# Create component template to use it multiple times - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components

This question might sound dumb, but I'll try it anyways:

**Is it possible to use a component multiple times, but with different content?** Something like a template.

*To be exact*, I want to write the component only once, but then use it in different places with different content - e.g. *(I don't know whether that makes any sense and if so, how to realize it)* by getting some text from an allocated model to fill a div, so that I can solely add a further model instead of editing the component itself?

Comment: If I understand you correctly there are several ways you can accomplish this. However, you need to show examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `<ng-content>`. Illustration:

app.component.html

```
<my-component>
   <p>I'm getting projected into a component from outside because of ng-content</p>
</my-component>
```

my.component.html

```
<p>Data from my own component</p>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
<p>Data from my own component</p>
```

By use of the `<ng-content>` you can *project* data from outside to within *your* component. You can make use of this in multiple ways, without changing the original component.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can pass data to a component using input.

```
<my-component [text]="myText"></my-component>
```

And then in the component you can get the text using:

```
@Input() text: Person;
```

And display it in your template

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-content for this. Please find the below pseudo code

```
<!-- card.component.html -->
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{ header }}
    </div>

    <!-- add the select attribute to ng-content -->
    <ng-content select="[card-body]"></ng-content>

    <div class="card-footer">
        {{ footer }}
    </div>
</div>

<!-- app.component.html -->

<h1>APP COMPONENT</h1>
<card header="my header" footer="my footer">

    <div class="card-block" card-body><!--  We add the card-body attribute here -->
        <h4 class="card-title">You can put any content here</h4>
        <p class="card-text">For example this line of text and</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">This button</a>
      </div>

<card>
```